# I want a php script such that used in stackoverflow.com

Tags: php

Yes, that's an old question, but I still can find what I want.
I want a php script like the stackoverflow.com's one.
I don't want drupal to develop it by myself, or phpbb3 with hacks, I don't want blogging systems such wordpress.
Clearly, I want an ASK script like this, with this specifications (like stackoverflow.com):

1. Easy to register when writing question or answering it.
2. People ask questions and others answers.
3. The comments on questions and answers are awesome.
4. Email notifications.
5. User profile.
6. "Related Questions" when writing a new one.
   That's the main ideas.

What Do You Think Is The Best Suitable Script Form My Site.

Comment: sometime when a page is not responding, a .NET message returned, so, i suspect is a .NET application

Comment: @ajreal SO is based on ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @ajreal - indeed (I should mention .NET are mostly for ASP)

Comment: There are a number of [Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones) clones available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of [Stack Overflow clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) available.

Answer (score 2):

> I want a php script like the
>   stackoverflow.com's one

Clones made with PHP:

- **[cahoots](http://cahoots.sourceforge.net/)**
- **[phpancake](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpancake/)**
- **[Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/)**
- **[Qwench](http://github.com/anantgarg/Qwench)**
- **[Qanda](http://www.qandasystem.com/)** PHP 5.2.3, Kohana MVC Framework 2.3.x

---

[Clones made with other languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)